# Need to add the cells if it is blank means blank if the sum is morethan 2 type as 1 and if sum is equal to 2 type as 0.5 else 0

Tags: excel-formula

I need to add up the cells. If it is blank - means blank, if the sum is more than 2 - type as 1, and if sum is equal to 2 - type as 0.5, otherwise 0.

Even if it's blank, I'm getting 0.

```
=IF(ISBLANK('period wise'!CF5),"",IF(SUM('period wise'!CF5:CI5)>2,"1",IF(SUM('period wise'!CF5:CI5)=2,"0.5","0")))
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine testing it. I think the cell referred to is showing no data, but contains a formula. To Excel that means it's not blank. You can refer to it as if `=IF(LEN('period wise'!CF5)=0,"",IF(SUM('period wise'!CF5:CI5)>2,1,IF(SUM('period wise'!CF5:CI5)=2,0.5,0)))`

PS I also removed the `"`'s around the results, not sure why you would want the numbers to output as text.